# How do I expand the first index of a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, vb6, expand

`ReDim` allows to expand my array. I'm wanna loop through an array and expand it, because I don't know which length my array is going to have.

I figured out that it's not possible to expand the first index of a multidimensional array.

Example:

```
ReDim Preserve Cells(1 To 100, 20) As Integer ' This works.
ReDim Preserve Cells(1 To 200, 20) As Integer ' This doesn't.
```

Is there a workaround? I can't figure out how I can program stuff in an elegant way without this. I'm used to program in `C#`.

Comment: Swap indices perhaps? There's no more elegant way; if you need to expand on both indices, then you need to copy contents or use some custom data structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an user defined type for the inner array, and use an array of this user defined type as your outer array

have a look at the following example:

```
Private Type MyArray
  strArray() As String
End Type

Private Sub RedimArray()
  Dim intFirst As Integer, intSecond As Integer
  Dim udt2D() As MyArray
  'resize first dimension
  ReDim udt2D(3) As MyArray
  For intFirst = 0 To UBound(udt2D)
    'resize second dimension for each separately
    intSecond = intFirst * 10 + 1
    ReDim udt2D(intFirst).strArray(intSecond)
  Next intFirst
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2871190: Be aware that this consumes more memory than a standard 2D array, though.